How to use datatransformer in symfony forms
Good morning,
I'm trying to create a dynamic form that returns country > region > city. However I'm having a problem choosing the region that is in a formIdentifier. My JS script returns me not an object but an integer. So I can't query my cities.
In my symfony profiler when i select one Dpt i have this error msg :
-messageTemplate: "The selected choice is invalid."
Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Constraints

Form {#1136 …}
-code: "1dafa156-89e1-4736-b832-419c2e501fca"
-cause:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
This is my entity :
Country (id, name)
Dpt (id, name, country_id)
City (id, name, dpt_id)
Thank you for your help
This is my form :
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\City;
use App\Entity\Country;
use App\Entity\Dpt;
use App\Entity\Ticket;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\CityToDpt;
use App\Repository\CountryRepository;
use App\Repository\CityRepository;
use App\Repository\DptRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TicketFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(private DptRepository $dptRepository, private CityRepository $cityRepository, private CityToDpt $transformer)
    {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Nom",
            ])
            ->add('message', null, [
                'attr' => ['rows' => 5]
            ])
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Country::class,
                'label' => "Pays",
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir un pays',
                'query_builder' => fn (CountryRepository $countryRepository) =>
                $countryRepository->findAllCountry()
            ])
            ->add('dpt', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Dpt::class,
                'label' => "Dpt",
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir un dpt',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                // 'disabled' => $country === null,
            ])
            ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => City::class,
                'label' => "Ville",
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une ville',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                // 'disabled' => $country === null,
            ]);


        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
            $dpts = $country === null ? [] : $this->dptRepository->findDptByCountry($country);

            $form->add('dpt', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Dpt::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir un département',
                'choices' => $dpts,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => "Département",

                // 'disabled' => $country === null,
            ]);
        };



        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier): void {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getName());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier): void {
                $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier): void {
                $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
            }
        );
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $formModifiers = function (FormInterface $form, Dpt $dpt = null) {
            $cities = $dpt === null ? [] : $this->cityRepository->findCityByDpt($dpt);

            $form->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => City::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une ville',
                'choices' => $cities,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                // 'disabled' => $country === null,
            ]);
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifiers): void {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifiers($event->getForm(), $data->getName());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('dpt')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifiers): void {
                $city = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifiers($event->getForm()->getParent(), $city);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('dpt')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifiers): void {
                $city = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifiers($event->getForm()->getParent(), $city);
            }
        );

        $builder->setAction($options['action']);
        $builder->get('dpt')
        ->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ticket::class,
        ]);
    }
}


This is my datatransformer :
<?php
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use App\Entity\Dpt;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class CityToDpt implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (issue) to a string (number).
     *
     * @param  Issue|null $issue
     */
    public function transform($issue): string
    {
        if (null === $issue) {
            return '';
        }

        return $issue->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (number) to an object (issue).
     *
     * @param  string $issueNumber
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (issue) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($issueNumber): ?Dpt
    {
        // no issue number? It's optional, so that's ok
        if (!$issueNumber) {
            return null;
        }

        $issue = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository(Dpt::class)
            // query for the issue with this id
            ->find($issueNumber)
        ;


        if (null === $issue) {
            $privateErrorMessage = sprintf('An issue with number "%s" does not exist!', $issueNumber);
            $publicErrorMessage = 'The given "{{ value }}" value is not a valid issue number.';

            $failure = new TransformationFailedException($privateErrorMessage);
            $failure->setInvalidMessage($publicErrorMessage, [
                '{{ value }}' => $issueNumber,
            ]);

            throw $failure;
        }

        return $issue;
    }
}

This my script JS :
                <script>
    const form = document.getElementById('ticket_form');
    const form_select_country = document.getElementById('ticket_form_country');
    const form_select_dpt = document.getElementById('ticket_form_dpt');
    const form_select_city = document.getElementById('ticket_form_city');


    const updateForm = async (data, url, method) => {
      const req = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'charset': 'utf-8'
        }
      });

      const text = await req.text();

      return text;
    };

    const parseTextToHtml = (text) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const html = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

      return html;
    };

    const changeOptions = async (e) => {
      const requestBody = e.target.getAttribute('name') + '=' + e.target.value;
      const updateFormResponse = await updateForm(requestBody, form.getAttribute('action'), form.getAttribute('method'));
      const html = parseTextToHtml(updateFormResponse);

      const new_form_select_dpt = html.getElementById('ticket_form_dpt');
      form_select_dpt.innerHTML = new_form_select_dpt.innerHTML;
    };

    const changeOption = async (e) => {
      const requestBody = e.target.getAttribute('name') + '=' + e.target.value;
      const updateFormResponse = await updateForm(requestBody, form.getAttribute('action'), form.getAttribute('method'));
      const html = parseTextToHtml(updateFormResponse);

      const new_form_select_city = html.getElementById('ticket_form_city');
      form_select_city.innerHTML = new_form_select_city.innerHTML;
    };

    form_select_country.addEventListener('change', (e) => changeOptions(e));
    form_select_dpt.addEventListener('change', (e) => changeOption(e));

    </script>


Did you consider using the PHP try catch block for handling the exception?
It could be achieved by declaring a validation function which returns true if the issue number is not null or otherwise return the TransformationFailedException.
function isValidIssue($issue, $issueNumber) {
    if($issue !== null) {
        return true;
    }

    $privateErrorMessage = sprintf('An issue with number "%s" does not exist!', $issueNumber);
    $publicErrorMessage = 'The given "{{ value }}" value is not a valid issue number.';

    $failure = new TransformationFailedException($privateErrorMessage);
    $failure->setInvalidMessage($publicErrorMessage, [
        '{{ value }}' => $issueNumber,
    ]);

    throw $failure;
}

After the validation function is declared you could use the try catch block
try {
    $issue = $this->entityManager
        ->getRepository(Dpt::class)
        // query for the issue with this id
        ->find($issueNumber);

    // Run the validation function
    $this->isValidIssue($issue, $issueNumber);
} catch(TransformationFailedException $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage();
}

